# Add duplicated rows in data frame

Tags: r

I have a CSV file (2.2 mln rows, 6.5 GB in size) in which I need to multiply data rows 3/4 times, so I get around 6-10 mln rows.

First time doing anything ever in R, so R might not be even the best tool to complete that (I just figured it might be).

What I was able to do so far is load data into dataframe using:

```
df <- read.table("MyFilePath", 
              header = TRUE,
              sep = ",")
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you just need to add another 'copy' of the same dataframe at the bottom of this one? in that case `df <- rbind(df, df)` will do that for you.

Comment: @Sven yes, I need exactly same data. It's just about creating larger data set for performance testing

Comment: `df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), 3), ]`

Comment: If unix based system, then try `df <- data.table::fread("cat file1.txt file1.txt file1.txt file1.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for-loop and `rbind` will do this:

```
repetitions <- 5
for (i in 1:repetitions) {
  df <- rbind(df, df)
}
```

You can change repetitions to any value of course. Keep in mind it's doubling every time, so you go from 2 to 4 to 8...

Comment: This solution will take some time due to iteratively rbinding data.frames. I wonder how it would fare against `xy[rep(1:nrow(xy), times = 5), ]`.